# Formulas to add not empty field and divide by number of not empty

Tags: formula

I have all month some with value others are empty.
I want to create a formulas to add all the value of the month not empty divided by the numbre of month not empty
exp: jan= 40, FEb=30  Avril= 20 Mars April june july=10
so i will have
(40+30+20+10)/4

How can i create a field formula.
If someone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to do something like this:

```
    (
    IF(ISBLANK(Field_1__c),0,Field_1__c)+
    IF(ISBLANK(Field_2__c),0,Field_2__c)+
    IF(ISBLANK(Field_3__c),0,Field_3__c)
        /*...and so on for all of your fields*/
    )
    /
    (
    IF(ISBLANK(Field_1__c),0,1)+
    IF(ISBLANK(Field_2__c),0,1)+
    IF(ISBLANK(Field_3__c),0,1)
        /*...and so on for all of your fields*/
    )
```

I'm assuming here that your fields store data as a number so that they can be manipulated in this way. You may need to create a condition to cover for the possibility that all fields are blank; I've never tried dividing by zero in a Salesforce formula, so I'm not entirely sure what happens in that case...

**/~~~~~~~~~~~~EDIT~~~~~~~~~~~~/**

According to the [help documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fixing_formula_errors.htm&language=en_US) if all fields are blank, this will return an #Error. So to cover this possibility, you'll need to cover that condition by wrapping the whole thing in an outer if statement like this:

```
IF(
    AND(
        ISBLANK(Field_1__c),
        ISBLANK(Field_2__c),
        ISBLANK(Field_3__c)
        /*...and so on for all of your fields*/
    ),
    null, 
    /*or zero or whatever you want to return in the condition where all fields are blank */
    (
        IF(ISBLANK(Field_1__c),0,Field_1__c)+
        IF(ISBLANK(Field_2__c),0,Field_2__c)+
        IF(ISBLANK(Field_3__c),0,Field_3__c)
        /*...and so on for all of your fields*/
    )
    /
    (
        IF(ISBLANK(Field_1__c),0,1)+
        IF(ISBLANK(Field_2__c),0,1)+
        IF(ISBLANK(Field_3__c),0,1)
        /*...and so on for all of your fields*/
    )
)
```

Comment: And if *every* field is blank?

Comment: @AdrianLarson updated my answer.